# How to query specific data from Facebook on Android integration?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated Facebook to my Android application.Now I want to fetch the information like specific posts which are only made by my application.

How can I do this ? Please help.

Edited.

In my application a user can post message to his wall.What I want is if user's friends also uses same application and post messages through the application.

So I want to retrieve all those messages of user from his wall which are made through the application(By him and his friends).

Comment: Please specify how you integrated Facebook into your Android application (e.g. by following the [Facebook Android SDK tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)) and which information you want to fetch *exactly* (e.g. which [Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you need).

Comment: I have integrated the same way you have mentioned & I want to fetch information of posts made by user himself and his friends on his wall & those posts should only be made through my application only.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "those posts should only be made through my application only". Could you clarify this and edit your question?

Comment: @JanGerlinger edited question.Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved problem my own.
I have used [fql](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for retrieving information I needed.

This is how I have used fql.
For retrieving messages & other data from my wall (only those which are made through my application).

```
private String getWallInfo()
    {
        try
        {

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("method", "fql.query");
            params.putString("query", "SELECT post_id, actor_id, app_id, message FROM stream where source_id = me() and app_id = "
                    + ConnectData.APP_ID);

            String response = facebook.request(params);
            Log.i(TAG, "response = " + response);
            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For retrieving messages & other data from my friends wall (only those which are made through my application).

```
 private String getFriendsWallInfo()
        {
            try
            {

                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("method", "fql.query");
                params.putString("query",
                        "SELECT post_id, actor_id, app_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND app_id="
                                + ConnectData.APP_ID);

                String response = facebook.request(params);
                Log.i(TAG, "response = " + response);
                return response;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```